# Why am I not able to loop through my JSON file?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am not able to loop through the contents of a JSON file because the JSON file starts with a '.' dot.

How do I clean the JSON file so that it removes the '.' dot in the begining of the file?

Find below my code:

```
  // Fetch API
  fetch(apiUrl, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    // Get the generated response from the API
    const generatedResponse = data.choices[0].text;


    // Console log out response
    console.log("smartResponse:: ", generatedResponse);

    for (let section in generatedResponse) {
      // Get the prompt for the current section
      let prompt = generatedResponse[section].prompt;
      
      // Do something with the prompt, like print it to the console
      console.log(`Prompt for ${section}: ${prompt}`);
    }
```

The code above yields:

```
smartResponse::  .

{
    "whatIsABox": {
        "prompt": "What is a box?",
        "section": "What is a box?"
    },
    "typesOfBoxes": {
        "prompt": "What are the different types of boxes?",
        "section": "Types of Boxes"
    },
    "usesForBoxes": {
        "prompt": "What are some uses for boxes?",
        "section": "Uses for Boxes"
    }
}

Prompt for 0: undefined
Prompt for 1: undefined
Prompt for 2: undefined
Prompt for 3: undefined
Prompt for 4: undefined
```

The desired result should be:

```
smartResponse::

{
    "whatIsABox": {
        "prompt": "What is a box?",
        "section": "What is a box?"
    },
    "typesOfBoxes": {
        "prompt": "What are the different types of boxes?",
        "section": "Types of Boxes"
    },
    "usesForBoxes": {
        "prompt": "What are some uses for boxes?",
        "section": "Uses for Boxes"
    }
}

Prompt for What is a box?: A box is a container with six faces.  The faces are made of six panels.  The panels are attached to each other with hinges or latches.  A box has a lid and a bottom.
```

Comment: If the file begins with `.` then it's not valid JSON.

Comment: @Barmar how do I make one by removing the '.'?

Comment: Interesting related read: https://www.json.org/json-en.html

Comment: @SirBT I added an answer with the live demo. Please have a look. I hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the response you mentioned in the OP, Looks like `data.choices[0].text` is returning a string. So to achieve this you can remove/replace that leading dot by using [`String.charAt(0)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt).

Demo **:**

```js
let generatedResponse = `.{
    "whatIsABox": {
        "prompt": "What is a box?",
        "section": "What is a box?"
    },
    "typesOfBoxes": {
        "prompt": "What are the different types of boxes?",
        "section": "Types of Boxes"
    },
    "usesForBoxes": {
        "prompt": "What are some uses for boxes?",
        "section": "Uses for Boxes"
    }
}`;

const jsonStr = generatedResponse.replace(generatedResponse.charAt(0), '');

const jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

for (let section in jsonObj) {
  // Get the prompt for the current section
  let prompt = jsonObj[section].prompt;
  
  // Do something with the prompt, like print it to the console
  console.log(`Prompt for ${section}: ${prompt}`);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`generatedResponse` is a string, not an object. You need to remove the `.` at the beginning, then parse it.

```js
fetch(apiUrl, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(requestBody),
  })
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
      // Get the generated response from the API
      const generatedResponse = data.choices[0].text;
      generatedResponse = JSON.parse(generatedResponse.replace(/^\./, ''));

      // Console log out response
      console.log("smartResponse:: ", generatedResponse);

      for (let section in generatedResponse) {
        // Get the prompt for the current section
        let prompt = generatedResponse[section].prompt;

        // Do something with the prompt, like print it to the console
        console.log(`Prompt for ${section}: ${prompt}`);
      }
```

Comment: Thanks but this didn't remove the dot.

Comment: Maybe it's not really a `.` character, but some other Unicode character that looks like it. You could use `generatedReponse.charCodeAt(0)` to find out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using for loop like this.

```
for (var key in generatedResponse) {
// skip loop if the property is from prototype
if (!generatedResponse.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;

console.log( generatedResponse[key].prompt );
}
```

Comment: Thanks but your solution didn't make any difference. 

The fact that the variable that holds the JSON is corrupted by that '.' dot in the beginning of the JSON results in the default output of:

`Prompt for 0: undefined
Prompt for 1: undefined
Prompt for 2: undefined
Prompt for 3: undefined
Prompt for 4: undefined`

Comment: `generatedResponse()` is a string, not an object. It won't have any of these keys, it needs to be parsed as JSON.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).